# After migrating to AGP 7 from FGP 6 all my custom gradle tasks disappeared from the gradle list

Tags: android

Before I had several dozen tasks. But now there are only a few left, 95% percent have disappeared from the list if you open the Gradle menu in the studio on the right. How to return it?

Comment: Do you specify a group for your custom tasks? If not, I'd assume AGP puts all of them under the `other` group, so perhaps you can look up your tasks there.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about new experimental option in Android Studio that turns off building gradle task list during sync (on by default for some reason). Go to settings -> experimental and uncheck "Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync". Screenshot attached:

[image: settings path]

Comment: No, it's unchecked already :(

Comment: Is the sync successful? Can you post logs from the "build" tab?